# Book of "introduction to logic" with French phrases as example

Tags: ressources, apprentissage

There is a book over logic in portuguese called "Introduçao à Logica" by the brazillian author Cezar A. Mortari. In this book there are a lot of examples of phases in informal language, and lots of exercises asking for translations from informal language to the formal language of logic. This is a great book to learn portuguese, in my opinion. So I was wondering if there are analogue books in french. I am just a beginner and this kind of books could help me a lot. I've found some books of formal logic but almost the entire book deal with formal statements only (I mean, in formal propositional/quantificational language).

Another great book is that by Irving Copi "Introduction to Logic". Is there a analogue french book?

(I would like to include the tag "demande-de-réference" but I don't have reputation enough for that)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

[Logique et langage - éditions Hermann](https://www.amazon.fr/Logique-langage-D%C3%A9duction-Jean-Pierre-Descl%C3%A9s/dp/2705669256)

Comment: Je me demande comment quelqu'un peut apprendre le français par un tel livre:-)! Mais c'est à la personne qui a posé la question de nous expliquer.

Comment: @dimitris If you take a look at one of the books I commented, you can see that theyare a big source of texts/phrases in various contexts where the reader can learn how to express ideas in a logic (or non-logic) way. A great piece of these books use the french language to construct and discuss the arguments, differently of other books about logic that are almost completely in symbolic language. I am searching for books of logic that, at least in part, present the theory of logic using examples/exercises in regular language (not with logic operators/symbols).

Comment: Cyril, I am wondering if the book you cited is what I am looking for. Do you know if we can have access to some piece of the book so we can take a look into the content and verify if it is what we want?